# position relative not shown in ios

Tags: html, css

On the PC, position relativity is displayed as it should.
If you go to the site via iPhone, the position relativity disappears somewhere and because of this the entire layout flies off.
https://angelika.pro/personal-two
Roman numerals have specifically left their places
How can this be fixed?

```
<tr style = "position: relative;">
   <td style = "left: 10px;">
   <td style = "right: 10px;">
</tr>

<style>
tr{
   position: relative;
}
td{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

no matter how strange it may be
but I just added display:flex; to tr and everything fell into place, how I still don’t understand but it works

```
    tr{
display:flex; 
justify-content: center;
}
```